# Mercurial Hosting software, alternatives?

Tags: deployment, mercurial, hosting, dvcs

Are there any software packages available for hosting Mercurial repositories **on my own server**, apart from the very basic script that comes with it?

I've looked over the [PublishingRepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories) wiki page at Mercurial, and the only viable alternative in that list is the `hgwebdir` script, which I've set up, but it's rather basic.

Does anyone make better website software for Mercurial hosting?

Comment: [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/opensource) supports Mercurial.

Comment: One thing to consider is that hgweb is kept in sync with new mercurial releases in a way that others aren't.  For example, mercurial-server, which hg-ssh with some repo management features, doesn't (didn't?) have subrepository support six months after mercurial added it.  Hgweb had it from day zero.

Comment: Some day the new Atlassian Stash might support Mercurial if enough people get their butts over here and vote for it. Requires signup (open to all). https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/STASH-2469

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's various ways to publish mercurial repositories as mentioned in the link you provided, but hgwebdir is the only method that supports multiple repos.

```
with hgwebdir.fcgi, you can use fastcgi and apache or nginx.
```

This can be useful for publishing multiple repos using web server.

Comment: So hgwebdir is the only software package available for hosting multiple repositories? There's nobody else that has made website software like this except for all the websites that you can host your code on? I've yet to find any of those that publishes their source code, for good reasons I'm sure, but I'd still like something that looks a bit more polished than hgwebdir.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen : I agree with you. There are no other options that I have seen. Most likely, they will be improvement upon hgwebdir. Using fcgi with nginx does work really good. At least that has been my experience but with a small limited team.

Comment: We should change the answer to RhodeCode : http://rhodecode.org/

Answer (score 9):

I would install the [**Kallithea** source code management system](https://kallithea-scm.org/) which is free software. It aims to be a hgweb replacement. It has a lot of features: repository management (creation, deletion, renaming), user management (even LDAP integration) and commit statistics.

Comment: hg-app is now known as RhodeCode.  It is open source and available at: rhodecode.org

Comment: @JimReineri: thanks, I've recently installed RhodeCode myself and I relaly like it. I've updated the answer to make it current.

Comment: RhodeCode is now commercial :(

Comment: @Gili: You can still find RhodeCode on PyPI: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RhodeCode and the source is available: https://secure.rhodecode.org/rhodecode-enterprise The core is under GPLv3 — I don't know exactly what parts isn't free software.

Comment: In case you want to install RhodeCode on shared(!) hosting like DreamHost (etc) like I did, you might want to check guide I wrote http://voukka.com/2014/02/installing-rhodecode-2-2-on-shared-hosting-like-dreamhost/

Comment: @Gili: I'm happy to announce that there is a fork of RhodeCode that is truly free sofware: [Kallithea](https://kallithea-scm.org/). That's what I would install on my server today.

Comment: @MartinGeisler, got it. See http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/4371 for a related discussion.

Answer (score 1):

[Kiln](http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/) is an alternative. Unlike [RhodeCode](http://rhodecode.org/) it is commercial (i.e. not free) and you have to setup / import any existing mercurial repositories, which can be a bit of work.

It can act as a public repository host since version 2.2.

Comment: RhodeCode is now commercial too :(